# JQPlot and C# response issues

Tags: c#, jquery, jqplot, webmethod

I have a JQPlot chart, calling a WebMethod is c#. The WebMethod calls out to a sp and returns a date and an amount. i am having issues with the returned data. Firebug reports the following:

SyntaxErrorL JSON.parseLunexpected character
   var = series = JSON.parse(data.d);

The response from my WebMethod is :

```
{"d":[{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":25000.00,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},    
{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":10000.00,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"}, 
{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":200000.00,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},
{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":69900.00,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},]}
```

WebMethod code:

```
     [WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod]
     public static List<GlobalClasses.jqplotModel> BuildCharts()
     {


    List<GlobalClasses.jqplotModel> newChart = new List<GlobalClasses.jqplotModel>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings 
     ["Conn"].ConnectionString))
     {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ChartData_Sel", conn))
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@senderBIC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11).Value = "ARBUGB2LXXX";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@messageType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = "103";
            cmd.Connection = conn;


            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dreader.Read())
                {
                    GlobalClasses.jqplotModel dataSet = new GlobalClasses.jqplotModel()
                    {
                        amount = dreader.GetDecimal(0),
                        ValueDate = dreader.GetString(1)
                    };
                    newChart.Add(dataSet);
                }
            }

        }

      }
        return newChart;
    }
```

being called from my HTML page like this :

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/BuildCharts",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var series = JSON.parse(data.d);
                chart = $.jqplot("chart", [series], chartOptions);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returned JSON is not well formated because you are having an extra `,` at the end of the last item. You can check it [here](http://jsonlint.com/). If you remove it you should not have parsing errors.

Try this instead

```
{"d":[{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":25000,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":10000,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":200000,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"},{"__type":"GlobalClasses+jqplotModel","amount":69900,"ValueDate":"2013-03-27"}]}
```

Comment: this si just a type on this page. the response object was a couple of thousand lines long, so i truncated it.